# Find all elements $m$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{42}$ such that $(12)+(m)$ is a proper ideal of $\mathbb{Z}_{42}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

This doesn't really sound too hard, and my guess is that it's all the even numbers in $\mathbb{Z}_{42}$ since if $m$ is any odd number it would seem that $(12) + (m) = \mathbb{Z}_{42}$. The system used to check for answers marks it wrong and I can't see why I'm wrong. Any tips appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen what happens with $m = 3$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I'm sorry if that's what it sounded like. I'm more convinced that I'm wrong but I can't see why.

Comment: Hint: you can use the fact that in $\mathbb{Z}$, we have $(n) + (m) = (\text{gcd}(n,m))$.

Comment: @D.Brito Sorry, now that I reread your question I see that I misinterpreted your last sentence.  "The problem is that the teacher is using WebWork"... so you're not getting useful feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint.** $(12)+(m)$ is not a proper ideal of $\mathbb{Z}_{42}$ if and only if $(12)+(m)=(1).$

Comment: Great! From this and other helpful tips I was able to gather that $m$ should be a multiple of $3$ or $2$ as they are the prime divisors of $12$.

Comment: It is worth noting how little the solution has to do with the number $42.$ This is one situation where the ambiguity inherent in the notation $(a)$ for a principal ideal is actually somewhat beneficial, as it suggests natural generalization.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a $a,b,c,p$ such that $p$ is a prime divisor of $a$,$b$, and $c$. Then $p$ will also divide every element of $(a)+(b)$. Thus, $(a)+(b)$ is a (not necessarily proper) subset of $(p)$. Since $(p)$ is a proper subset of $\mathbb{Z}_c$, $(a)+(b)$ is also a proper subset of $\mathbb{Z}_c$. Thus, in the problem you present, it is at least sufficient (I haven't addressed necessity) condition to find a number that shares a prime factor with 12 and 42. 2 is one such number, but 3 is as well.

Another way of putting it is that if $gcd(a,b)$ is not a unit in  $\mathbb{Z}_c$, then $(a)+(b)$ is a proper ideal.